# Unable to Get the Online Presence of my friends list on FaceBook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

This is my fql:

```
$fql = "SELECT uid, name, online_presence, status 
         FROM user 
        WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '".$user_id."') ";
```

The `online_presence` value always return `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your query...

just replace

```
WHERE uid IN
```

to

```
WHERE 2 IN
```

**Query**

```
$fql = "SELECT uid, name, online_presence, status 
         FROM user 
        WHERE 2 IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '".$user_id."') ";
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea178/1)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to retrieve the `online_presence` key value if you try querying Facebook without a Facebook access token. For example:

```
SELECT uid, name, online_presence, status FROM user WHERE uid IN (4,5,6)
```

Without an access token set, returns:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 4, 
      "name": "Mark Zuckerberg", 
      "online_presence": "", 
      "status": null
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 5, 
      "name": "Chris Hughes", 
      "online_presence": "", 
      "status": null
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 6, 
      "name": "Dustin Moskovitz", 
      "online_presence": "", 
      "status": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Whereas, with an access token set, returns:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 4, 
      "name": "Mark Zuckerberg", 
      "online_presence": "offline", 
      "status": null
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 5, 
      "name": "Chris Hughes", 
      "online_presence": "offline", 
      "status": null
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 6, 
      "name": "Dustin Moskovitz", 
      "online_presence": "offline", 
      "status": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Make sure you are setting a valid Facebook access token (in PHP with the official Facebook SDK, looks like: `$facebook->setAccessToken($your_access_token);`) and have the appropriate permissions to access the data.

Permissions are likely the cause of "status" returning `null` in both responses. I'm not friends with Mr. Zuckerberg.